# How use a NumberFormat function on google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, format, google-apps

I have a webapp that I get a value. I make an append row with this data for my sheet. However, I want that this data have a text format, because I want to get the value like I typed.
Some problems happen with my sheet, like an "and" be recognized as a number.
Ex: 2000e7 appears as: 2.00E + 10.
I know that yhave a function to change the format. `NumberFormat (" ")`

But I think that I'm not using it correctly.

My code:

```
  var ws=  ss.getSheetByName(flag);
  ws.appendRow([Entrada,Modelo,SN,Ocorrencia,Status,data,obs])

  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss2.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("My Last row");

// Money format
range.setNumberFormat("@");
```

Comment: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

Comment: Can you provide an output of what `Logger.log(Entrada,Modelo,SN,Ocorrencia,Status,data,obs)` looks like and how you want the result to look in the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the better way is to prepend the value with `'` rather than using `setNumberFormat`

Related

- [Script 'setValues' method interprets strings as numbers in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57091209/1595451)